# Delete word before and after the cursor in nano editor

Tags: text-editor, nano, editing

How can I delete the word before and the word after the current position of the cursor in nano editor? (For the sake of clarity: I mean two distinct editions under this description, like the Ctrl-Backspace and Ctrl-Delete in Windows).

And how can I delete the text between the beginning of the current line and the position of the cursor?

Answer (score 3):

Save this file to `~/.nanorc` and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> cuts the word to the left, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd> cuts right

```
bind    ^]          cutwordleft         main
bind    ^\\         cutwordright        main
```

This works for me in nano version 2.5

Comment: the most recent version of nano broke because now ctrl-\ is used to search and replace. thanks nano.

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way to do this in `nano`, but there are some key combinations that can accomplish what you want.

One useful tip to start is to open `nano` using the `-W` option, to make word boundaries work in a more sensible manner.

> -W, --wordbounds 
>      Detect word boundaries more accurately by treating punctuation characters as parts of words.

**Delete the word before the current position of the cursor**

1. Switch on marking - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>
2. Move forward one word - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
3. Cut (delete) the selection - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

**Delete the word after the current position of the cursor**

1. Switch on marking - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>
2. Move backward one word - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
3. Cut (delete) the selection - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

**Delete from the current cursor position to the beginning of the line**

1. Switch on marking - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>
2. Move to beginning of current line - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. Cut (delete) the selection - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

These command will work as described in a normal terminal, though the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is swallowed by some editors (if I've connected through Windows cmd by ssh). You can use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to replace <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: later version of nano allow users to bind the `cutwordleft` and `cutwordright` functions to keyboard shortcuts using `~/.nanorc`

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> : Delete the word after the current position of the cursor

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Backspace</kbd> : Delete the word before the current position of the cursor

nano version 4.8

Comment: Both hotkeys delete the LINE not the word, nano v. 5.4.

Comment: Seems to work in 7.2??